# range-based for loop for istringstream

Tags: c++

I'm reading lines from a file via std::getline, i'd like to do some further processing for each word in the line. I'm aware that range based for loops require an iterator with a begin member so I tried to used **std::istream_iterator** but appareantly it's not enough, what's wrong with this? Why can't I use this expression in my for loop?

```
    std::istringstream words(line);
    for (const auto& s : (std::istream_iterator<std::string>(words)))
    {
           // print each word here
    }
```

Also, I know i can solve it with  **boost::range::istream_range** but how do I go about this without boost?

Comment: Why don't use the shortest `for (words >> s)`?

Comment: range based for loops work on a ranges.  A single iterator is not a range.

Comment: The expression on the rhs of the `:` either needs to be a array or be something that provides begin and end iterators either via member functions `expr.begin()` and `expr.end()` or via free functions `begin(expr)` and `end(expr)`...

Answer (score 1):

Wrong method:

```
while(!iss.eof())
{
    std::string word;
    iss >> word;
    std::cout << word;
}
```

Right method:

```
for(std::string word; iss >> word;)
    std::cout << word;
```